# Nuget & Team Foundation Server offline error

Tags: tfs, nuget

I have Team Foundation Server 2012 Express set up, and it seems to be working fine. However, when I try to add a NuGet package when not connected to TFS, I get the following error:

> Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core 1.2'.
>
> Install failed. Rolling back...
>
> TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server [My TFS Server].
>
> Technical information (for administrator):
>
> Unable to connect to the remote server

It doesn't seem to matter whether the package is from the web or from our internal repository. Package Restore is enable, if that is relevant.

Is there some way I can still add and update packages while offline? What does TFS have to do with adding a package anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following steps solved that issue for me (VS2012 Premium Update 3):

1. Check out your project when you're still connected (alternatively
   make the packages.config and your *.csproj file writable)
2. After you lost connection to the TFS, close your solution and open
   it again. VS should ask you whether to go offline. Say yes.
3. Install the NuGet packages.
4. Connect to TFS again.
5. Bring your solution online (within the solution explorer select the solution, and open File/Source Control/Go Online)
6. Check in the changes on *.csproj and packages.config.

Comment: I'll try it when I've next got access to that machine, thanks!